# stringify variable is not a string? o_O PHP pass incorrectly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I trying to pass an string from Javascript to PHP. To do so I stringify my variable  `myString = JSON.stringify(myString)`, validate the result with a `console.log(myString)` and call an ajax execution. Which should pass this string to PHP.

It seems this ajax execution modified my string somehow, that the PHP throws an error, that the passed string is an array. To validate this I do a `print_r($data)`, which throws an array back.

What do I miss? I want to decode the passed data, but PHP claim it is not a string.

```
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost/json_push.php",
                method:"post",
                data: myString,
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }
            })
```

[image]

Comment: This is seemingly not Vanilla JavaScript. If you're using jQuery, the `data` key expects any arbitrarily complex data structure and will serialise it automatically. If you do it yourself, you're basically sending an empty string where your serialised variable is the field name. You can verify that in the browser developer console ("Network" tab).

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're doing on the PHP side or what you expect.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots of text, it makes it really hard to read. Also, you say you're print `$data` in PHP, but don't show where that's come from - in fact, you don't show any PHP at all, so it's impossible to tell if what you're doing there makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing data without json stringify in ajax.you can pass object to ajax data

```
$.ajax({
   url:"http://localhost/json_push.php",
   method:"post",
   data: {
   id:5,
   type:"drinks"
    },
   success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
   }
})
```

Comment: I did that before which is working but after JSON_decode I got annoying "\" in the string. I thought by passing a string straight away I can get rid of it.

Comment: directly print_r